# How to get first String based on whitespace out of a full String using java8?

Tags: string, arraylist, java-8

Let's Example I have String s = "Rahul Kumar" I need to have Rahul as a output using java8

Actual Requirement, I do have a list of Trip Object, I want to set driverName property as only first name to each Trip Object and return that list?

```
System.out.println( someStringValue.subSequence(0, someStringValue.indexOf(' ')));
```

I'm getting trouble to incorporate this code into the listOfTrip. If I'm doing like this,

```
List<CharSequence> list = listOfTrips.stream().map(e -> e.getDriverName().subSequence(0, someStringValue.indexOf(' '))).collect(Collectors.toList()); System.out.println(list);
```

Here, With this, The return type is wrong and it is not fetching only first name out of full name.

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried ?

Comment: If you just want to get the first word, then you can use split function from java

Comment: Adding split function gives array of string @DeepakPatankar

Comment: @ErRahulRaj Don't post the code as a comment. You should [add it to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72001909/edit) so that everyone can see it.

Comment: "The return type is wrong and it is not fetching only first name out of full name "

Can you please explain what is the expected output and what is wrong with the above solution?

Comment: Would need more code to find your problem. With just the streaming part, if input list was a list of String (driver names), the extraction of the fist part before `" "` works just fine.

Comment: The question is, I do have a listOfTrip. In a list, I do have Trip Object. Trip Object having one property that is, private String driverName; The requirement is, Let's suppose, driverName = "Rahul Kumar"; is there with Trip Object1, driverName="Josh Edgar"; is there with Trip Object2. I wanted to have a list, where, list contains Trip Objects and driverName would be like this, Rahul with Trip Object1, driverName would be Josh with Trip Object2. Ultimately, I need to have a list of Trip Objects having the firstname of driverName. @DeepakPatankar

Comment: The question is, I do have a listOfTrip. In a list, I do have Trip Object. Trip Object having one property that is, private String driverName; The requirement is, Let's suppose, driverName = "Rahul Kumar"; is there with Trip Object1, driverName="Josh Edgar"; is there with Trip Object2. I wanted to have a list, where, list contains Trip Objects and driverName would be like this, Rahul with Trip Object1, driverName would be Josh with Trip Object2. Ultimately, I need to have a list of Trip Objects having the firstname of driverName. @cyberbrain

Comment: That's not the string, I do have a listOfTrip Object, In Trip Bean, there's a property called private String driverName; @cyberbrain

Comment: I know that this is not a list of String for you, but nevertheless: a [mre] is needed to help you further

Comment: Of course, `indexOf` and `subSequence` must be invoked *on the same string*, so `e.getDriverName().subSequence(0, someStringValue.indexOf(' '))` does not work.

Comment: listOfTrips.forEach(e -> Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(e.getDriverName());@DeepakPatankar

Comment: listOfTrips.forEach(e -> Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(e.getDriverName()); Not Giving the result as expected. @DeepakPatankar

Answer (score 1):

Below will give you the proper result:

```
List<CharSequence> list2 = listOfTrips.stream()
                        .map(m->m.getDriverName().substring(0,m.getDriverName().indexOf(' ')))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I wanted to have listOfTrip Object @pryakks

Comment: The above code gives [John, Jane, Rahul], I need listOfTrip Object @pryakks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this also once:

```
String s = "Rahul Kumar";
Optional<String> beforeWhiteSpace = Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(s).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().findFirst();
```

Comment: There is no point in inserting `.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()` into the operations.

Comment: Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(s).findFirst();
I think this should be fine right? @Holger

Comment: Yes, that’s it.

Comment: for (Trip trip : listOfTrips) {
   trip.setDriverName(trip.getDriverName().substring(0,trip.getDriverName().indexOf(' ')));
  }
     
     System.out.println(listOfTrips);  Output :   [Trip [driverName=John], Trip [driverName=Jane], Trip [driverName=Rahul]]  --->  It is working well and fine, please suggest me the possible way of doing this with java8 streams. @Holger

Comment: @ErRahulRaj there is no point in using a stream for this. You can use `listOfTrips.forEach(trip -> trip.setDriverName(trip.getDriverName().substring(0,trip.getDriverName().indexOf(' ') )));` if you don’t like conventional `for` loops. You can avoid the code repetition by using `trip.getDriverName().replaceFirst(" .*", "")` instead of `trip.getDriverName().substring(0,trip.getDriverName().indexOf(' '))`

Comment: It worked like a charm. Can't thank you enough for your valuable time and your great concern. @Holger